# Throw exception from closure

Tags: dart

I've been trying to setup a simple Serversocket and I would like to have an exception thrown (other than some other stuff ie. setting a var to false) if some error is encountered, it works using an external callback but what about closures? 
The Dart editor gives me an error and refuses to run it!

```
Server(String address,int port,int backlog)
{
    this.s = new ServerSocket(address,port,backlog);
    this.s.onError = (e) => throw new Exception(e);
}
```

I've tried also "throw e" and stuff like that, but as long as "throw" is present the ide won't run it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had the same problem, Dart seams to be unable to accepts throws in single line closures. You should be able to do:

```
Server(String address,int port,int backlog)
{
    this.s = new ServerSocket(address,port,backlog);
    this.s.onError = (e) {
       throw new Exception(e);
    };
}
```

I have not looked in the spec so I don't know if its intentional or is a bug.

Comment: So, as William Hesse from Google said on the mailing list "throw <expression> is a statement, not an expression, so it can only
go in a statement block" so it's a design choice, I guess.